# Woocommerce - Can I somehow use shipping in order as a line item (product) instead of a fee?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running WooCommerce based store which is connected to our company's economic software by imports of stock status and exports of completed orders. Now what I need is to include shipping and additional fee in orders AS products WITH catalog numbers so the orders get imported to our system already with the cost of the shipping and we don't have to write it manually. Is there any way of making that happen? I'm little bit familiar with PHP but haven't found such a code or plugin.

Every sort of help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable shipping from your admin panel.

Now create an item Named shipping. Use hook 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents'

Inside this call back if the shipping item is not present in the cart then add it.

You can use own logic before adding this based on cart items.

Hope this helps.